# What kind of matrix is this?

Tags: matrix

[image: Matrix Exmaple]

This is a weird matrix. 
If the input is 1 then output is 1.
But if input is 2 then output is matrix 3^2. 
The most weird is if input 3 then output is matrix 5^2. 
Anyone know how to solve this problem?
I really need the answer to get a job!

Comment: What do you mean by 3^2 and 5^2? And if this is a job interview question just look at the output and it should become clear how to do this. It does you no favors if someone else does it for you.

Comment: Does it help to know that the dimension is `( 2 * n ) - 1` ?

Comment: Yeah, it helps. Thank you @Kingsley.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straghtforward. the dimension of the matrix if (2*input)+1 and the numbers in the matrix is the distance from the center + 1.  please see below python code.

```
import math

def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    dist = (x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2)
    return int(math.sqrt(dist))+1

if __name__=='__main__':
    x = int(input())
    if(x < 1):
        exit()
    dimension = (2*x)-1
    center = dimension // 2
    mat = [[None for i in range(dimension)] for i in range(dimension)]
    for i in range(dimension):
        for j in range(dimension):
            mat[i][j] = distance(center, center, i, j);
            print(mat[i][j], end=' ')
        print('')
```

Comment: no, I don't use phyton. According to those codes, I know it cannot get the same result as the output in the image. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It should be pretty straghtforward to migrate the logic to any other language you use. If you are facing issues add you code to question and I can check

Comment: I used php but it doesn't have operator // like in Phyton.

Comment: Anyone can help me? I really need the job. I know how to make program but when it comes to Matrix, I am lost of it.

Comment: that is the integer division operator. in php you can use intdiv(dimension, 2) or you can  use floor(dimension/2). either would work.
It would be better if you could share were you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I've got how to do it in php, but I don't know how to optimize the code. 
Anyone know how to do it correctly?

```
<?php   
$z = 3; 
$dimension = (2 * $z) -1 ;  

for($i = 1; $i <= $dimension; $i++)
{
    for($j = 1; $j <= $dimension; $j++)
    { 
        if(($i == 1|| $j == 1) || ($i == $dimension || $j == $dimension)){
            echo $z . " "; 
        } else if(($i == 2 || $j == 2) || ($i == $dimension - 1 || $j == $dimension - 1)){
            echo $z - 1 . " "; 
        }
        else if(($i == 3 || $j == 3) || ($i == $dimension - 2 || $j == $dimension - 2)){
            echo $z - 2 . " "; 
        }
        else if(($i == 4 || $j == 4) || ($i == $dimension - 3 || $j == $dimension - 3)){
            echo $z - 3 . " ";
        }
        else{
            echo $z - 4 . " "; 
        }

        if($j == $dimension){
            echo "</br>"; 
        }
    }       
}
```

?>